# Find "abc", replace with "abc"+####

Tags: vba, replace, find, wildcard

I have a dataset with content e.g. "abc1234", "abc2345", "abc3456" etc.

The "abc" part is the constant and my way to find them.

But when I have found them I would like to replace/ delete the constant part and 3 characters of the variable part.

e.g. Find "abc"-> result = "abc1234" -> Replace "abc123" with "".

I have tried to do it with something like below. Using the # as a wildcard for each variable position/ character. But does not work...

```
Selection.Replace what:="abc", Replacement:=""+###, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to put the wilcard in the search pattern, not in the replace. Also, for a single character, the wildcard is `?`

```
Selection.Replace what:="abc???", Replacement:="", _
   LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
   :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

'input   -> output
'abc1234 -> 4
'abc2345 -> 5
'abc3456 -> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function replace()?

Replace("abc1234", "abcd123", "") gives 4

Comment: OP is using the replace function. What he is trying to do is remove `abc???` where `?` is any character. Your answer works only for a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative possibility without Search and Replace:

```
Dim ra As Range
For Each ra In Selection
    If Left(ra.Value, 3) = "abc" Then
ra.Value = Mid(ra.Value, 7, 50)
    End If
Next
```

Worked on my Excel

Comment: Well, if I understood correctly there may be other data that shouldn't be replaced. _The "abc" part is the constant and my way to find them._